# unknown option "--syn" when apply iptables rules

Tags: iptables

My system is centos 7,below is my setting rule of iptalbes:

```
-A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 72.188.0.0-72.188.255.255 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,995,3306 -j ACCEPT
```

This setting is for allow only dedicated IP range to access ports 22,995,3306.

But I got error as below:

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.21: unknown option "--syn"
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `-p tcp` option before `--syn`:

```
-A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 72.188.0.0-72.188.255.255 -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m multiport --dports 22,995,3306 -j ACCEPT
```